# Java exited with code 1 (MSB6006) - Xamarin.Droid

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have tried out a lot of solutions on how to get this resolved. My debug works alright. But as at now, i am trying to build archive my apk in the release mode. When i re-build in the release mode i get the error `Java exited with code 1 (MSB6006)`.

Proguard and multi-dex is enabled in my Droid project. My heap size is also set already to 1G. I also created a proguard.cfg file in my Droid project but i still get the same error.  When i check the error reference, it leads to me this in my browser `MSBuild.ToolTask.ToolCommandFailed`.

Is there any other i could solve this ?

Attached is the https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e7fba8cc745ce9ae06fa2c8ae075697  - Full Diagnostic Build Output.

**proguard.cfg**

```
# This is Xamarin-specific (and enhanced) configuration.

-dontobfuscate

-keep class mono.MonoRuntimeProvider { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.MonoPackageManager { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.MonoPackageManager_Resources { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.android.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.java.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class mono.javax.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk.platform.android.AndroidGameView { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk.GameViewBase { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk_1_0.platform.android.AndroidGameView { *; <init>(...); }
-keep class opentk_1_0.GameViewBase { *; <init>(...); }

-keep class android.runtime.** { <init>(***); }
-keep class assembly_mono_android.android.runtime.** { <init>(***); }
# hash for android.runtime and assembly_mono_android.android.runtime.
-keep class md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.** { *; <init>(...); }
-keepclassmembers class md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.** { *; <init>(...); }

# Android's template misses fluent setters...
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.view.View {
   *** set*(***);
}

# also misses those inflated custom layout stuff from xml...
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.view.View {
   <init>(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet);
   <init>(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a full diagnostic build output. This will be the truth of the error. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

There are most likely proguard warnings that need to be resolved. You can use the `-dontwarn` option if you really wanted to.

Comment: @JonDouglas,  i have included the link to what you asked for, please

Comment: This link shows a 404.

Comment: I fixed the error please

Comment: You most likely need to update the Gist URL. This is still a 404.

Comment: sorry i mean i found a solution to this question by just quiting and restarting about twice my project. I don't know how that solved it

Answer (score 5):

Turn on MultiDex

RightClick on Xamarin.Android--->Goto Properties-->AndroidOptions-->Now Enable MultiDex

[image]

**Now Clean and Rebuild your solution**

We had similar issues and nailed it down to our app going over 65k methods limit (which could be what's happening when you reference google play services).

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

The below link useful for you

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44381/project-wont-build-keeps-failing-with-error-message-java-exe-has-exited-with-code-2

Comment: `exited code 2` vs `exited code 1` can be very different. The OP has already stated "Proguard and multi-dex is enabled in my Droid project."

Comment: Kudos for you my friend

Answer (score 1):

ProGuard and MultiDex on Xamarin.Android need a little extra work.

Related to ProGuard, it may be removing some Java classes from your APK and causing bugs. You need to create a proguard.cfg file and set its Build Action to ProguardConfiguration. By the way, it is not necessary to set the Heap size to 1G.

Related to MultiDex, you also need to create a MultiDexApplication class that extends Application.

If you are using the Android SDK for Windows, you need to update proguard.jar to its latest version and also change mainClassesDex.bat.

Comment: I am running my project on a Mac and like i stated in the question, i already created a proguard.cfg file (whose build action is set to ProguardConfiguration).

Comment: Does your proguard.cfg file has the same content as you provided in the answer? You don't need to copy Xamarin default proguard.cfg into a new proguard.cfg.

Comment: Yeah just like i have in the answer. How do i get it then please? and is the proguard.cfg suppose to be placed in a specific folder?

Comment: No, you don't need to a specific folder. In the Documentation link, there is a full tutorial about ProGuard and MultiDex on Xamarin.Android to help.

Comment: But then i can't really tell from my build output if the issue is related to your answer